# vagrant on windows error 'cannot load such file' nokogiri

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to run a `vagrant up` command to create a box on AWS. The vagrant file already works on my Mac now I'm trying to run on Windows. I've just installed the latest Vagrant for Windows (1.8.1) and installed the AWS Plugin.

When I run `vagrant up` I get the following output

> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in
>   require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (Load Error)
>   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in
>   rescue in '
>       from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in
>   '
>       from C:/Users/renato.mintz/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-xml-0.1.2/lib/fog/xml.rb:2:in
>   require'
>       from C:/Users/renato.mintz/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-xml-0.1.2/lib/fog/xml.rb:2:in
>   `'
>       from C:/Users/renato.mintz/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-1.37.0/lib/fog.rb:13:in
>   require'
>       from C:/Users/renato.mintz/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/fog-1.37.0/lib/fog.rb:13:in
>   '
>       from C:/Users/renato.mintz/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.7.0/lib/vagrant-aws/action/connect_aws.rb:1:in
>   require'
>       from C:/Users/renato.mintz/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.7.0/lib/vagrant-aws/action/connect_aws.rb:1:in
>   '
>       from C:/Users/renato.mintz/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.7.0/lib/vagrant-aws/action.rb:97:in
>   block in action_read_state' ...

and it continues...

I've found some posts about `nokogiri` not running on ruby for Windows 2.2 but I'm not sure if this has any fix yet.

Any clue on how to fix or bypass this issue?

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue (https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6766), pending fix, caused by vagrant fixing a low version of nokogiri.

In the meantime, in `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\specifications\vagrant-1.8.1.gemspec` you'll find the gemspecs with the problematic nokogiri references.

Change the nokogiri reference in `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\specifications\vagrant-1.8.1.gemspec` and `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\specifications\vagrant.gemspec` (if it exists) from `<nokogiri>, ["= 1.6.3.1"]` to `<nokogiri>, [">= 1.6.3.1"]` (note the `>=` as opposed to `=`).

Once you've done this, you can then run the following to allow vagrant access to a version of nokogiri that isn't problematic:

`vagrant plugin install nokogiri --plugin-version 1.6.7.1`

Vagrant up should then work once more. Hopefully an updated version of vagrant isn't too far off now anyhow.

Comment: The most promising information I've seen yet on this issue, but alas despite making the changes as outlined I'm still not able get past this error.

Your results may vary.

Comment: IIRC there are 3 places in the vagrant 1.8.1 gemspec that require changing, dos you get all 3? (Only ask since the above has worked on both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 R2, with multiple minor versions of Ruby 2), otherwise details of your system set up may help figure out a workaround that works for all.

Comment: Rich yes, I did replace all three instances. I'm on Win 10, don't know if that's an issue but I'm still facing problems with vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-share --plugin-version 1.1.8
```

Found at:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8519